# Can we create an index on a Switch... Case in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, switch-statement, match, pymongo

I have a HUGE collection. I am using `match` to do a filter on values I set by `CASE` statement. Can I create an index on that text value?

This is my Query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
{
    '$match': {
        'date': {
            '$gte': '2019-07-15',
            '$lte': '2019-08-14'
        },
        'xyz': 'abc'
        },
    },
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'b_version': '$b',
        'b_main':
                    {'$switch': {
                        'branches': [
                            { 'case': {'$gt': [{'$indexOfCP': ['$b', "Google Plus"]} ,-1]}, 'then': 'GP' },
                            { 'case': {'$gt': [{'$indexOfCP': ['$b', "Facebook"]} ,-1]}, 'then': 'FB' },
                            { 'case': {'$gt': [{'$indexOfCP': ['$b', "Instagram"]} ,-1]}, 'then': 'IG' },
                            { 'case': {'$gt': [{'$indexOfCP': ['$b', "Snapchat"]} ,-1]}, 'then': 'SC' },
                        ],
                            'default': 'Other'
                    }
                },
        },
        'b_ct': {'$sum': 1},
        'starts': {'$sum': '$starts'},
        'completes': {'$sum': '$completes'}

}
}, {
    '$project': {
        '_id': 0,
        'b_version': '$_id.b_version',
        'b_main': '$_id.b_main',
        'b_ct': '$b_ct',
        'starts': '$starts',
        'completes': '$completes',
    }
}, {'$match': {'b_main': 'SC'}},
{ '$sort': { 'b_main': 1, 'b_version': 1}, }
])
```

I want to set an `index` on `b_main`. Is there a way to do that? I actually want to set it on `date, xyz and a text match on b_main`

Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `$switch` case cannot be directly indexed.

Index usage by aggregation framework operations is described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes). Most importantly:

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index
>   when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.

A `$group` stage would not be indexed directly, but you can redesign your operation to be more efficient, either in terms of:

- Ensuring that the initial retrieval of data being passed to the $group is efficiently indexed, or..
- Reducing the amount of unnecessary data being passed into the $group stage

Looking at your operation, it seems that you are only interested in documents where `b_version` contains `Snapchat`. Instead of passing all documents to `$group` and filtering out unnecessary documents at the end, you should consider adding a filter on `b_version` to the initial `$match` stage to reduce the number of documents entering the pipeline.

The initial `$match` stage would then be able to use the index: `{ xyz: 1, b_version: 1, date: 1 }`.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: The problem here comes when I have to filter for the "Other"